# обернуть текст из дива в p

Tags: javascript, jquery

Тема изъезженная, но все же у меня не удается она

```
    (function($) {
  $.fn.wrapSelected = function(open, close) {
    return this.each(function() {
      var textarea =$("#myTextArea");
      var value = textarea.html();
      var start = textarea[0].selectionStart;
      var end = textarea[0].selectionEnd;
      textarea.html(
        value.substr(0, start) + 
        open + value.substring(start, end) + close + 
        value.substring(end, value.length)
      );
    });
  };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function () {

$("#but1").click(function(){

$("#myTextArea").wrapSelected('<p>', '</p>');
});
```

Разметка

```
 <div contenteditable="true"  name="text" id="myTextArea" ></div></br>

            <div id="but1">Абзац</div>
```

С textarea работает с div нет,но самая основа в том,что как сделать так,что бы происходило аналогично с wysiwyg?
https://jsfiddle.net/1nxpggr2/1/

Comment: у дива нет значения, в отличие от textarea, можно взять только innerHTML

Comment: ой,спасибо,тут лажанул,не подскажите,теперь почему то дублирование происходит

Comment: обратите внимание на значения `var start = textarea[0].selectionStart;
      var end = textarea[0].selectionEnd;`

Comment: не подскажите как к конечному обратиться?

Comment: к конечному чему?

Comment: `var start = textarea[0].selectionStart; var end = textarea[0].selectionEnd;`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36791/discussion-between-grundy-and-zkolya).